# Rhino Mocks, VerifyAllExpectations

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, rhino-mocks

I would like to track a call to a method with Rhino Mocks. Let's assume I have this code:

```
public class A
{
    protected IB _b;

    public A(IB b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }

    public void Run( string name )
    {            
        _b.SomeCall(new C { Name = name });
    }
}    

public interface IB
{
    void SomeCall( C c );
}    

public class C
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // more attributes here
}
```

And the test looks like:

```
// prepare
var bMock = Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IB>();
bMock.Expect(x => x.SomeCall(new C { Name = "myname" }));
var sut = new A(bMock);

// execute
sut.Run("myname");

// assert
bMock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

The test fails with a *ExpectedViolationException* because Rhino Mocks framework detects 2 distinct C classes.

How do I check the call if the subject under tests creates the object parameter into the method under test? Any chance to tell Rhino Mocks to check the parameter as "Equals"?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend you use the much easier (and more maintainable) AAA syntax. In most cases, strict mocks are more of a pain than anything else.

the arguments are compared using `Equals`. If `C` doesn't override `Equals`, it is compared by reference and won't match in your case. Use `Matches` to check the argument in some other way.

```
// arrange
var bMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IB>();
var sut = new A(bMock);

// act
sut.Run("myname");

// assert
bMock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SomeCall(Arg<C>.Matches(y => y.Name == "myname"));
```

Comment: Hi, the compiler says: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.AbstractConstraint' because it is not a delegate type." pointing "x => x.Name = "myname""

Comment: fixed the assignment equals (=) to comparison (==).

Comment: still same problem. I am missing something? http://imageshack.us/f/708/errorah.png/

Comment: reuse of the same lambda argument name x. Fixed it. (y => ...)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add IgnoreArguments and can additionally add parameter contraints for the call to 'SomeCall':

```
bMock.Expect(x => x.SomeCall(new C { Name = "myname" }))
    .IgnoreArguments()
    .Constraints(new PropertyConstraint(typeof(C), "Name", 
        Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Equal("myname")));
```

Comment: thanks mate! nice trick I learned today. That issue was bugging me for weeks.

Comment: This syntax is out of date. You should use the newer AAA syntax, where you don't need property names in strings anymore. An there is no use to pass a new C if you ignore the arguments in the next line.